the sign of CASSCF CI coefficients from GAMESS
GAMESS-US shows the CASSCF wavefunction as
STATE   1  ENERGY=      -228.4986615272  S=  0.00  SZ=  0.00  SPACE SYM=A



ALPHA
BETA
COEFFICIENT




1101
0111
-0.3661831


0111
1101
-0.3661831


1011
1011
0.3443194


1101
1011
0.0352037


1011
1101
0.0352037



I know the singlet configuration can give as the substraction of two determinants ( for example here 1101 | 0111 -0111 | 1101 ). However, here I can see the same sign.
If I understand correctly, the wavefunction of this singlet is
Phi_singlet=-0.3661831(1101 | 0111 - 0111 | 1101)+0.3443194( 1011 | 1011 |)+0.0352037(1101 | 1011-1011 | 1101 |). 

Am I right?
Now the triplet
STATE   2  ENERGY=      -228.4986613675  S=  1.00  SZ=  0.00  SPACE SYM=A   




ALPHA
BETA
COEFFICIENT




0111
1011
-0.3946927


1011
0111
0.3946927


0111
1101
-0.3033454


1101
0111
0.3033454


1011
1101
0.2916734


1101
1011
-0.2916734



It means
Psi_triplet=-0.3946927(0111 | 1011 +1011 | 0111 )-0.3033454( 0111 | 1101+1101 | 0111)+0.2916734(1011 | 1101+1101 | 1011).

Is it true?
